# Ignore missing element for the tour in tour.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I am using intro.js in a dynamic page and if all the elements provided are present, the tour goes fine without any issues.

But if any of the element is not present, the page being dynamically generated, the tour stops and have to press NEXT button twice to proceed further.

Is there any way to skip the step altogether if the element is not present?

**Example:**

```
intro.setOptions({
   steps[
      {"element":".ow_status","intro":"status"}, 
      {"element":".ow_mailbox","intro":"mailbox"},
      {"element":".ow_test","intro":"test"}
   ] 
});
```

In the above example, if the element with class ow_mailbox is not present, the tour stops in the middle and it shows 3 steps although only 2 is with valid element.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can filter the array and only return elements that exist. The new options would look like this:

```
intro.setOptions({
   steps: [
      {"element":".ow_status","intro":"status"}, 
      {"element":".ow_mailbox","intro":"mailbox"},
      {"element":".ow_test","intro":"test"}
   ].filter(function (obj) {
      return $(obj.element).length;
   })
});
```

Comment: Wow. You made the problem to look silly :) Thanks alot.

Comment: This assume that there is always a target element. What if in between the tour I have a step that don't target any element?

Comment: How can I do this in Angular 7, not using JQuery?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem but on a responsive template.  Depending on viewport, my elements were present but were hidden.  I had to use this code instead.

```
intro.setOptions({
  steps: [
    {"element":".ow_status","intro":"status"}, 
    {"element":".ow_mailbox","intro":"mailbox"},
    {"element":".ow_test","intro":"test"}
  ].filter(function (obj) {
    $(obj.element).is(':visible');
  })
});
```

Comment: The new build of intro.js has fixes related to my issue. So  you could try that.

Comment: I tried 7.0 and it was still including the steps in the top left corner for the hidden elements. This was the only option that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To improve just a bit the answer of @Neil and allow **floating steps** too, just add this:

```
intro.setOptions({
   steps: [
      {"element":".ow_status","intro":"status"}, 
      {"element":".ow_mailbox","intro":"mailbox"},
      {"element":".ow_test","intro":"test"}
   ].filter(function (obj) {
      return $(obj.element).length || obj.element == ".introjsFloatingElement";;
   })
});
```